# Text overlapping with drop-down

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have CSS code from a template design that a client wants to use.  One of the issue I'm having is that, once a text option is selected (those options with wide length) is writing over the drop-down arrow.

[See image](http://s15.postimage.org/6n96cm10b/overlapping.png)

I have tried using z-index and placing overflow:hidden where appropriate.  Here is the CSS code:

```css
/* search drop-down values */
select option {}
option.level-0{padding:0 3px;}
option.level-1,option.level-2,option.level-3,
option.level-4,option.level-5,option.level-6,
option.level-7{}
.selectBox-dropdown{ height: 34px; min-width:190px; max-width: 320px;                     position:relative; border:solid 1px #BBB; line-height:1; text-decoration:none; color:#666; outline:none; vertical-align:middle; background:#FFF; -webkit-border-radius:6px; -moz-border-radius:6px; border-radius:6px; display:inline-block; cursor:default; margin-top: 1px\9; height: 33px\9;}
.content_right .selectBox-dropdown {width:303px;}
.content_right a.selectBox-dropdown:hover {text-decoration:none;}
.selectBox-dropdown:focus,
.selectBox-dropdown:focus .selectBox-arrow{border-color:#BBB}
.selectBox-dropdown.selectBox-menuShowing{-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0; -moz-  border-radius-bottomright:0; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0; border-bottom-left-radius:0; border-bottom-right-radius:0}
.selectBox-dropdown .selectBox-label{width:100%; padding:0 .7em; line-height:2.4em; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; font-size:14px}
.selectBox-dropdown .selectBox-arrow{position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:23px; height:100%; background:url(images/sb-arrow.png) 50% center no-repeat; border-left:solid 1px #BBB;  }
.selectBox-dropdown-menu{position:absolute; z-index:99999; max-height:200px; border:solid 1px #BBB; background:#FFF; -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2); box-shadow:0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2); overflow:auto}
.selectBox-inline{width:250px; outline:none; border:solid 1px #BBB; background:#FFF; display:inline-block; -webkit-border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; border-radius:4px; overflow:hidden;} 
.selectBox-inline:focus{border-color:#666}
.selectBox-options,
.selectBox-options li,
.selectBox-options li a{list-style:none; display:block; cursor:default; padding:0; margin:0}
.selectBox-options li a{color:#666; padding:1px .7em; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; background:6px center no-repeat; text-decoration:none; font:14px/1.5em Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
.selectBox-options li.selectBox-hover a{background-color:#EEE}
.selectBox-options li.selectBox-disabled a{color:#888; background-color:transparent}
.selectBox-options .selectBox-optgroup{color:#666; background:#EEE; font-weight:bold; line-height:1.5; padding:0 .3em; white-space:nowrap;}
.selectBox.selectBox-disabled{color:#888 !important}
.selectBox-dropdown.selectBox-disabled .selectBox-arrow{opacity:.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50); border-color:#666;}
.selectBox-inline.selectBox-disabled{color:#888 !important}
.selectBox-inline.selectBox-disabled .selectBox-options a{background-color:transparent !important}
```

code for the drop-down:

```
<div class="state-dropdown"><?php wp_state_dropdown() ?></div>

<span id="campus_dropdown"><?php if (empty($_GET['cp_state'])){ wp_campus_dropdown();} ?></span>
<?php if (!empty($_GET['cp_state'])){?>
<script type="text/javascript" >loadXMLDoc('<?php echo $_GET['cp_state'];?>','<?php echo $_GET['cp_your_college'];?>')</script>
 <?php }?>
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.  I know this is a bit too much of CSS, but again its from a template and I have been pulling my hair out for weeks!

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: give a demo in jsfiddle with the html.

Comment: I don't think that he will be able to do that. I guess it's some kind of wordpress theme. He/her should give us a live example to analyze - his website.

Answer (score 0):

First of all without sample HTML, we can only guess at how the css is used. After analyzing the css you provided, I took a stab at how I thought it might be used, [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ewCtG/). Based on this assumption there are two options:

- Set a right padding for the elements that contain the menu options. This may cause the dropdown to widen, but should be better as it will allow users to see the entire text of the option.
- Set the background for the dropdown arrow element ('.selectBox-arrow') to a solid color and match the border radius of the containing element. Note that the background color defaults to transparent.

If for whatever reason neither of these options work in your situation, remember, Firebug (or other browser's developer tools) are your friend. These tools can help make short work of problems like this.